# How do I use the output file generated from a program as the input for another program? batch file

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, trx

I'm running unit tests with Visual Studio which takes this as the command on the cmd:

```
vstest.console.exe C:\Desktop\Project\UnitTests\Debug\UnitTests.dll /Logger:trx
```

Once that executes it generates a .trx file (visual studio test result file). Next I want to take this file and run it through a program called trx2html that will generate a html file from it that is in a readable format. The command for this is:

```
trx2html.exe trxResultFile
```

This seems fairly simple but I can't seem to get the second part to work. My problem is that the first program generates a filename so I can't just type this filename after the trx2html.exe.

Here is my bat file so far:

```
@echo %1

SET ProjectPath=%1
SET VsTest=vstest.console.exe %ProjectPath% /Logger:trx
SET TestWindowPath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow"
SET TestResults="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\TestResults\"

cd /d %TestWindowPath%

pause

%VsTest%

trx2html.exe "%TestResults% | %VsTest%"
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: So you don't know what the file name looks like which is used by the first tool? how do you want to find the created file -- just per file extension `.trx`? which location? what if there are more than only one?

Comment: It is stored in the TestWindowPath shown above, they are saved in format: username_computername_date_time.trx

Comment: Okay, that means you need to look up the most recent `*.trx` file, right? if so, you could either parse the file name and extract the date portion, or to use the file (modification) date, which I would go for: `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D "%TestWindowPath%\*.trx"') do set "FILE=%%~fF"` (this sets variable `FILE` to the full path of the most recent file)

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Got it to work with a similar solution, thanks!

Comment: You might provide your solution as an answer to show what you did; you may even mark it as accepted later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I used:

```
cd /d %TestResults%

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b *.*') do set RECENT=%%x
echo %RECENT%

SET trx=trx2html.exe "%RECENT%"

%trx%
```

and the whole program:

```
@echo %1

SET ProjectPath=%1
SET VsTest=vstest.console.exe %ProjectPath% /Logger:trx


SET TestWindowPath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow"

SET TestResults=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\TestResults\

cd /d %TestWindowPath%

%VsTest%

cd /d %TestResults%

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b *.*') do set RECENT=%%x
echo %RECENT%

SET trx=trx2html.exe "%RECENT%"

%trx%
```